# How can I go back one step when processing a list of (user) choices?

Tags: vbscript, back, inputbox

I have a series of user choices (implemented as input boxes). Short Example:

```
Answer = InputBox("Choose: 1 - One 2 - Two", "Choose"))
If Answer = "1" Then 
    Answer = InputBox("Choose: 1 - Hi 2 - Hello", "Choose"))
        If Answer = "1" Then....
```

I want to know if VBScript can go back one step to the previous choice. From

```
InputBox("Choose: 1 - Hi 2 - Hello   3 - BACK", "Choose"))
```

If I input 3 I want to go one step back. I try  `history.go(-1)`, but there is an error. He want object "history".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "go one step back"?  Are you wanting it to go the line that precedes `Answer = InputBox("Choose...` line?

Comment: In that Example I want go from Line where is Hi and Hello back into the line One Two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the first selection in a Do loop, and break out of the loop with `Exit Do` only if something other than 3 is selected in the second prompt.

```
Do
    Answer = InputBox("Choose: 1 - One 2 - Two", "Choose")

    If Answer = "1" Then 
        MyVal = LevelTwoSelect
    End If

    If MyVal <> 3 Then Exit Do

Loop

Function LevelTwoSelect

    Answer = InputBox("Choose: 1 - Hi 2 - Hello  3 - BACK", "Choose")
        If Answer = "1" Then LevelTwoSelect = 1
        If Answer = "2" Then LevelTwoSelect = 2
        If Answer = "3" Then LevelTwoSelect = 3

End Function
```